# Sublime text, SFTP directory structure

Tags: sftp, sublime-text-plugin

My remote server has this structure (Laravel app):

```
- laravel
----app
----bootstrap
----(etc.)

- public_html
----js
----css
----index.php
----(etc)
```

BUT, my local structure is laravel's default structure

```
---app
---bootstrap
---(etc)
---**public** (remote's public_html)
```

So, I have two FTP users. One is "laravel" and its remote root folder is "laravel". The other is "public" and its remote folder is "public_html".

When I upload with "laravel" user, I don't have any problem, but when I upload a file with "public" user, the file is uploading in "public_html/public/whatever-file". This is because my local and remote structure are not exactly the same.

**How can I say to sftp-config.json when I upload a file to public_html, "removes" the "public" name to the uploaded directory?** That way it will save correctly.

Thx.

Comment: The whole story comes because the laravel project is in a shared hosting.

Comment: Why not just make your local structure mirror the server one?

Comment: Because I can't change my web root directory in the shared hosting. It says that is not save to put all the files into "public_html", in addition to "play" with .htaccess to make things work. (hide "public" in the url)

Comment: what I meant was, change your *local* structure. So, instead of Laravel's default, have a `public_html` and `laravel` directory *locally*. The server stays the same. That way, you can directly sync from local to remote and back.

Comment: Yep, I thought that, the problem is that I cannot connect via FTP to the "root" folder, I can connect either "laravel" or "public_html" . Shared hosting ftw...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, the best solution would be to make your local filesystem match the remote filesystem, with two directories: `laravel` and `public_html`. Since you don't have access to their parent directory on your shared server, you'll need to then set up two SFTP servers in Sublime, one pointing to `public_html` and the other to `laravel`. This way, you don't need to worry about hacking SFTP to rewrite file paths, something which I don't think is possible anyway as it is not open-source.